# Add Attributes to OpenStreetMap Data in ESRI that was already Loaded?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, openstreetmap

I followed some instructions to load OpenStreetMap Data into a geodatabase for our companies footprint using the "Load OSM Data" in the OpenStreetMap Toolbox for ArcMap. My end goal was to create a network dataset using this data. It has finally completed after running for about 2 weeks. I was reading another instruction set that added this information to the steps that were not included in the first Instructions I read initially.

```
    Expand the optional Adjust Input Schema parameter and add the following OSM tag keys to schema:

admin_level
bridge
content
craft
drinking_water
emergency
ford
generator:source
maritime
name
name:en
office
oneway
pump
ref
religion
seasonal
tower:type
tunnel
The following tags are optional. They are required for a network dataset. Adding these tags at this stage speeds up the creation of the network dataset if it is required:
access
construct
maxheight
maxspeed
proposed
smoothness
surface
```

I am hoping there is a method or a tool where I can add these attributes that I did not load initially to the dataset. This is a somewhat time-sensitive project and I sadly do not have 2 weeks to do this over again.

Comment: It might take much longer than two weeks to try to extract just the missing pieces then join them, and the resulting database would likely be badly fragmented without further long-running maintenance. You might need to try both *and* find a way to improve your I/O throughput on this task.

Comment: That's what I was worried about. Sadly I'm not sure what else I can do to improve the performance. I am only doing the footprint of our Fiber Network already, not the whole planet OSM file, and I am also doing everything on an SSD. Looks like it may be back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I tried out the OSM Attribute Selector, and it seemed to work in a reasonable amount of time adding my missing attributes. (~9 hours). It is not ideal but better than another 2 weeks!

[image]

Comment: Yes, the "OSM Attribute Selector" is designed for that task. The "osmTags" column in fact holds all OSM tags for each imported object, and it is from this column that the "OSM Attribute Selector" tool extracts the missing information to create true columns.